# При создании чат-бота фиксации модели выдает ошибку. Не понимаю, что нужно сделать. Помогите)

Tags: python

```
    random.shuffle(training)
    training = np.array(training)
    output = np.array(output)

    train_x = list(training[:,0])
    train_y = list(training[:,1])
    print("Training data created")

    from keras.layers import Dropout
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(128, activation = 'relu', input_shape=(len(list(training[0])),)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(len(list(training[0])), activation='softmax'))

    learning_rate: float = 0.01
    momentum = 0.9
    nesterov = True
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=learning_rate, momentum=momentum, 
    nesterov=nesterov)
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

    hist = model.fit(np.array(train_x), np.array(train_y), epochs=200, batch_size=5, verbose=1)
    model.save('chatbot_model.h5', hist)

    print("model created")
```

выдает следующую ошибку:

```
Epoch 1/200
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Рабочий стол\АЯковлев\1уроки\2информатика\проект\train_chatbot.py", line 108, in <module>
    hist = model.fit(np.array(train_x), np.array(train_y), epochs=200, batch_size=5, verbose=1)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\Рабочий стол\АЯковлев\1уроки\2информатика\проект\.idea\vinv\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\frenc\AppData\Local\Temp\__autograph_generated_fileid8d49tc.py", line 15, in tf__train_function
    retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
    ^^^^^
ValueError: in user code:

File "E:\Рабочий стол\АЯковлев\1уроки\2информатика\проект\.idea\vinv\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py", line 1401, in train_function  *
    return step_function(self, iterator)
File "E:\Рабочий стол\АЯковлев\1уроки\2информатика\проект\.idea\vinv\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py", line 1384, in step_function  **
    outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
File "E:\Рабочий стол\АЯковлев\1уроки\2информатика\проект\.idea\vinv\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py", line 1373, in run_step  **
    outputs = model.train_step(data)
File "E:\Рабочий стол\АЯковлев\1уроки\2информатика\проект\.idea\vinv\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py", line 1150, in train_step
    y_pred = self(x, training=True)
File "E:\Рабочий стол\АЯковлев\1уроки\2информатика\проект\.idea\vinv\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
File "E:\Рабочий стол\АЯковлев\1уроки\2информатика\проект\.idea\vinv\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\input_spec.py", line 253, in assert_input_compatibility
    raise ValueError(

ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'sequential' (type Sequential).

Input 0 of layer "dense" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=2, found ndim=1. Full shape received: (None,)

Call arguments received by layer 'sequential' (type Sequential):
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None,), dtype=int32)
  • training=True
  • mask=None
```